# Angular.js making repeated requests and never loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications, httprequest

I'm in the process of learning Angular.js, so I have a simple Node app serving a very basic Angular web page and writing simple log data to stdout. Up until now, this has worked just fine, but now, for no known reason, every time I try to load the page, the page doesn't load (and eventually crashes) and until I am forced by memory issues to kill it, this happens in the Node app:

```
My-iMac:Learning Angular.js me$ node node-app.js
Incoming request for /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846525840
Loaded page /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846525840
Incoming request for /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846526063
Loaded page /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846526063
Incoming request for /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846526340
Loaded page /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846526340
Incoming request for /js/3.js?_=1443846526389
Loaded page /js/3.js?_=1443846526389
Incoming request for /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846526398
Loaded page /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846526398
Incoming request for /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846526637
Loaded page /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846526637
Incoming request for /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846526645
Loaded page /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846526645
Incoming request for /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846526693
Loaded page /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846526693
Incoming request for /js/3.js?_=1443846526698
Loaded page /js/3.js?_=1443846526698
Incoming request for /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846526739
Loaded page /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846526739
Incoming request for /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846526751
Loaded page /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846526751
Incoming request for /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846526758
Loaded page /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846526758
Incoming request for /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846526789
Loaded page /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846526789
Incoming request for /js/3.js?_=1443846526795
Loaded page /js/3.js?_=1443846526795
Incoming request for /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846526802
Loaded page /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846526802
Incoming request for /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846527180
Loaded page /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846527180
Incoming request for /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846527190
Loaded page /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846527190
Incoming request for /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846527220
Loaded page /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846527220
Incoming request for /js/3.js?_=1443846527225
Loaded page /js/3.js?_=1443846527225
Incoming request for /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846527235
Loaded page /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846527235
Incoming request for /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846527246
Loaded page /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846527246
Incoming request for /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846527254
Loaded page /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846527254
Incoming request for /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846527266
Loaded page /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846527266
Incoming request for /js/3.js?_=1443846527281
Loaded page /js/3.js?_=1443846527281
Incoming request for /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846527340
Loaded page /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846527340
Incoming request for /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846527363
Loaded page /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846527363
Incoming request for /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846527935
Loaded page /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846527935
Incoming request for /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846527957
Loaded page /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846527957
Incoming request for /js/3.js?_=1443846527963
Loaded page /js/3.js?_=1443846527963
Incoming request for /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846527973
Loaded page /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846527973
Incoming request for /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846528005
Loaded page /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846528005
Incoming request for /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846528019
Loaded page /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846528019
Incoming request for /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846528031
Loaded page /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846528031
Incoming request for /js/3.js?_=1443846528035
Loaded page /js/3.js?_=1443846528035
Incoming request for /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846528043
Loaded page /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846528043
Incoming request for /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846528056
Loaded page /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846528056
Incoming request for /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846528065
Loaded page /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846528065
Incoming request for /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846528141
Loaded page /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846528141
Incoming request for /js/3.js?_=1443846528496
Loaded page /js/3.js?_=1443846528496
Incoming request for /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846528520
Loaded page /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846528520
Incoming request for /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846528546
Loaded page /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846528546
Incoming request for /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846528553
Loaded page /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846528553
Incoming request for /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846528564
Loaded page /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846528564
Incoming request for /js/3.js?_=1443846528605
Loaded page /js/3.js?_=1443846528605
Incoming request for /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846528643
Loaded page /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846528643
Incoming request for /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846528656
Loaded page /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846528656
Incoming request for /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846528679
Loaded page /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846528679
Incoming request for /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846528694
Loaded page /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846528694
Incoming request for /js/3.js?_=1443846528700
Loaded page /js/3.js?_=1443846528700
Incoming request for /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846528708
Loaded page /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846528708
Incoming request for /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846528726
Loaded page /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846528726
Incoming request for /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846529054
Loaded page /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846529054
Incoming request for /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846529083
Loaded page /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846529083
Incoming request for /js/3.js?_=1443846529088
Loaded page /js/3.js?_=1443846529088
Incoming request for /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846529096
Loaded page /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846529096
Incoming request for /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846529128
Loaded page /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846529128
Incoming request for /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846529331
Loaded page /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846529331
Incoming request for /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846529354
Loaded page /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846529354
Incoming request for /js/3.js?_=1443846529657
Loaded page /js/3.js?_=1443846529657
Incoming request for /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846529679
Loaded page /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846529679
Incoming request for /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846529694
Loaded page /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846529694
Incoming request for /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846529728
Loaded page /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846529728
Incoming request for /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846529740
Loaded page /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846529740
Incoming request for /js/3.js?_=1443846529744
Loaded page /js/3.js?_=1443846529744
Incoming request for /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846529751
Loaded page /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846529751
Incoming request for /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846529764
Loaded page /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846529764
Incoming request for /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846529795
Loaded page /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846529795
Incoming request for /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846529902
Loaded page /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846529902
Incoming request for /js/3.js?_=1443846529943
Loaded page /js/3.js?_=1443846529943
Incoming request for /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846529950
Loaded page /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846529950
Incoming request for /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846529967
Loaded page /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846529967
Incoming request for /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846530108
Loaded page /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846530108
Incoming request for /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846530137
Loaded page /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846530137
Incoming request for /js/3.js?_=1443846530144
Loaded page /js/3.js?_=1443846530144
Incoming request for /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846530153
Loaded page /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846530153
Incoming request for /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846530165
Loaded page /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846530165
Incoming request for /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846530173
Loaded page /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846530173
Incoming request for /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846530189
Loaded page /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846530189
Incoming request for /js/3.js?_=1443846530196
Loaded page /js/3.js?_=1443846530196
Incoming request for /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846530204
Loaded page /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846530204
Incoming request for /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846530611
Loaded page /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846530611
Incoming request for /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846530844
Loaded page /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846530844
Incoming request for /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846530857
Loaded page /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846530857
Incoming request for /js/3.js?_=1443846530862
Loaded page /js/3.js?_=1443846530862
Incoming request for /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846530898
Loaded page /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846530898
Incoming request for /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846530909
Loaded page /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846530909
Incoming request for /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846531006
Loaded page /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846531006
Incoming request for /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846531021
Loaded page /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846531021
Incoming request for /js/3.js?_=1443846531140
Loaded page /js/3.js?_=1443846531140
Incoming request for /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846531146
Loaded page /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846531146
Incoming request for /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846531501
Loaded page /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846531501
Incoming request for /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846531520
Loaded page /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846531520
Incoming request for /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846531680
Loaded page /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846531680
Incoming request for /js/3.js?_=1443846532119
Loaded page /js/3.js?_=1443846532119
Incoming request for /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846532128
Loaded page /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846532128
Incoming request for /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846532161
Loaded page /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846532161
Incoming request for /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846532359
Loaded page /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846532359
Incoming request for /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846532386
Loaded page /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846532386
Incoming request for /js/3.js?_=1443846532396
Loaded page /js/3.js?_=1443846532396
Incoming request for /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846532414
Loaded page /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846532414
Incoming request for /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846532619
Loaded page /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846532619
Incoming request for /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846532634
Loaded page /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846532634
Incoming request for /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846533444
Loaded page /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846533444
Incoming request for /js/3.js?_=1443846533472
Loaded page /js/3.js?_=1443846533472
Incoming request for /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846533480
Loaded page /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846533480
Incoming request for /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846534037
Loaded page /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846534037
Incoming request for /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846534046
Loaded page /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846534046
Incoming request for /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846534058
Loaded page /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846534058
Incoming request for /js/3.js?_=1443846534191
Loaded page /js/3.js?_=1443846534191
Incoming request for /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846534253
Loaded page /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846534253
Incoming request for /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846534282
Loaded page /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846534282
Incoming request for /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846534298
Loaded page /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846534298
Incoming request for /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846534343
Loaded page /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846534343
Incoming request for /js/3.js?_=1443846534349
Loaded page /js/3.js?_=1443846534349
Incoming request for /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846534362
Loaded page /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846534362
Incoming request for /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846534377
Loaded page /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846534377
Incoming request for /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846534385
Loaded page /libs/angular.min.js?_=1443846534385
Incoming request for /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846534401
Loaded page /libs/angular-route.min.js?_=1443846534401
Incoming request for /js/3.js?_=1443846534409
Loaded page /js/3.js?_=1443846534409
Incoming request for /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846534416
Loaded page /libs/jquery.min.js?_=1443846534416
Incoming request for /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846534427
Loaded page /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1443846534427
```

Here is the code for Angular:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        controller: 'MainController',
        templateUrl: './main6.html'
    })
    .when('/company', {
        controller: 'CompanyController',
        templateUrl: './company6.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
}]);

app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.companies = [{
        heading: 'text1',
        content: 'Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. '
    }, {
        heading: 'Text2',
        content: 'Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. '
    }, {
        heading: 'SoMe3',
        content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus dapibus egestas mauris. Etiam blandit turpis a sapien pretium condimentum. Duis dapibus arcu ac tellus euismod, non feugiat est vulputate. Cras nec sodales felis. Sed ac massa lacus. Nunc in tellus a ante fermentum consectetur a at nulla. Cras nec egestas. '
    }, {
        heading: 'Pickles',
        content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi erat augue, tristique a sollicitudin nec, rhoncus et nisi. Aenean at mi ex. Sed tincidunt euismod porttitor. Quisque varius elit in efficitur placerat. Morbi quis turpis facilisis, congue purus ut, vehicula felis. Nam ex nulla, pellentesque vitae ipsum eget, tincidunt luctus.'
    }, {
        heading: 'Dill',
        content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi erat augue, tristique a sollicitudin nec, rhoncus et nisi. Aenean at mi ex. Sed tincidunt euismod porttitor. Quisque varius elit in efficitur placerat. Morbi quis turpis facilisis, congue purus ut, vehicula felis. Nam ex nulla, pellentesque vitae ipsum eget, tincidunt luctus.'
    }];
});

app.controller('CompanyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.companies = [{
        heading: 'text1',
        content: 'Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. '
    }, {
        heading: 'Text2',
        content: 'Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. '
    }, {
        heading: 'SoMe3',
        content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus dapibus egestas mauris. Etiam blandit turpis a sapien pretium condimentum. Duis dapibus arcu ac tellus euismod, non feugiat est vulputate. Cras nec sodales felis. Sed ac massa lacus. Nunc in tellus a ante fermentum consectetur a at nulla. Cras nec egestas. '
    }, {
        heading: 'Pickles',
        content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi erat augue, tristique a sollicitudin nec, rhoncus et nisi. Aenean at mi ex. Sed tincidunt euismod porttitor. Quisque varius elit in efficitur placerat. Morbi quis turpis facilisis, congue purus ut, vehicula felis. Nam ex nulla, pellentesque vitae ipsum eget, tincidunt luctus.'
    }, {
        heading: 'Dill',
        content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi erat augue, tristique a sollicitudin nec, rhoncus et nisi. Aenean at mi ex. Sed tincidunt euismod porttitor. Quisque varius elit in efficitur placerat. Morbi quis turpis facilisis, congue purus ut, vehicula felis. Nam ex nulla, pellentesque vitae ipsum eget, tincidunt luctus.'
    }];
});
```

**Why is the Angular app making continuous requests and re-requests for the files, instead of loading and behaving normally? If it helps, this problem began when I was tinkering with routing.**

#### Update 1:

When I change this:

```
.when('/company', {
    controller: 'CompanyController',
    templateUrl: './company6.html'
})
```

to this:

```
.when('/company', {
    controller: 'CompanyController',
    templateUrl: './main6.html'
})
```

no more requests come into the server, and "/company" loads the same page as "/". Obviously this makes the page rather useless, if every url can only load the same template, but the information may be helpful. Of note is that "main6.html" and "company6.html" are basically identical, except for some changed text.

#### Update 2:

I've figured out that whenever I use `./main6.html` as the template url it works, but when I use `./company6.html`, it doesn't. This means that this issue is isolated to loading the `/company` page, and the `/` page loads just fine. I've checked for typos in company6.html, misspellings of the file name, errors in the html, but the html is almost identical to that of main6.html, with only a few differences in text.

#### Update 3:

Here is the code for main6.html (company6.html has different lorem ipsum, but is otherwise the same):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">NYSE Companies</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</h1>
        <p>Quisque ultrices libero quis fringilla tempor. Ut egestas sapien posuere lorem eleifend bibendum. Duis et pellentesque ex, id scelerisque urna. Nullam ullamcorper molestie urna, eget lobortis eros finibus eu. Donec a vulputate nisi. Quisque eget ullamcorper nulla.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Company" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" data-ng-model="search">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" data-ng-repeat="company in companies | filter: search">
            <h2>{{company.heading | uppercase}}</h2>
            <p>{{company.content}}</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#/company" role="button">View details »</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <footer>
        <p>Wibbly Wobbly Timey Wimey</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Here is the code for 6.html, the actual main page that loads angular, and contains the templates:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Lipsum Dipsum</title>
    <link href="./libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 50px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-ng-view></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./libs/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./libs/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./libs/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/3.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've encountered this issue in the past with single page applications. Check to make sure that all of your templateUrls point to existing file paths.

My node single page application server would default to serving an index.html file whenever it would normally serve a 404 page. So, when a directive had a templateUrl that did not exist, the server would serve index.html in its place. The script tags inside of index.html would subsequently be loaded and the whole process would repeat.

My best suggestion for debugging this issue would be to visit each templateUrl independently in your browser.

Comment: Nice, this was it. Given my experience in security, I included in the Node server I threw together a whitelist of allowed pages. If a page was requested outside the whitelist, the homepage would be served instead, resulting in the above issue. This was a tough bug to crack, considering the whitelist is the last place you'd expect this problem to start.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have created a infinite loop in you route config

Try it like this

`$routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
        controller: 'MainController',
        templateUrl: './main6.html'
    })
    .when('/company', {
        controller: 'CompanyController',
        templateUrl: './company6.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });`

It looks to me like the otherwise condition will route you to example.com/, but if you just add a / to the end a website it will remove it when its loaded in turn sending you back to your otherwise state.

I don't have access to test this right now but I'm pretty sure this is the problem.

Comment: I was really hoping that was it. I changed it to your example ('/main' instead of '/home', but same idea) and it didn't seem to help. Interestingly, it worked the first time I entered the /company url, but once I tried again it didn't. It may have just been that it cached the script the first time, and so was still using the old system.

Comment: There are no script tags in the templates

Comment: When navigating to the site you need to go to  example.com/#/home.  Angular navigation does not actually reload the page it just changes the ng-view base on what is after the # in the url.

Comment: Is example.com/#/main not equivalent, so long as the javascript file is set up for it? In my case, example.com/#/main actually loads fine, but the problem above results from example.com/#/company

Comment: Yes it is, I was pretty sure you where doing this correct because you said it worked once.  Could  you post the html code?

Comment: If you open up the developer tools on your browser with f12 do you see any errors in the consol?

Comment: It's very difficult to open, because while the page tries to load the browser and computer grind to a near-halt until I kill the server, but yes. The error 'WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.' keeps repeating